# Is there any moderator guideline?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Helly Everyone!

I'm quite new to this site and StackExchange in general. I try to actively participate in the moderator activity of the site to make it better. I try to keep my votes, editing etc. consistent and try to learn from other people's example. I'd like to ask if there is /are any guideline(s) other than the short info on each privilege. Thank you!

Comment: Reading questions and answers here in meta is useful to get a feel for a particular site.

Comment: When you use the word moderator, are you speaking of site mods? Or your moderation privileges? I ask because from the wording of your post, it sounds like you are speaking of your moderation actions not a site moderator.

Comment: MattDMo's answer is great! However, IMHO, if you really want to understand how things work in SE, I would suggest wandering through meta.SE to find more posts regarding general questions about StackExchange. Just right now I can think of these two: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/ and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202168/why-is-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange-in-general-so-scary/1 (This one is really, really nice.)

Answer (score 7):

[Jeff Atwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) (one of the founders of Stack Exchange) wrote this blog entry back in 2009 entitled [*A Theory of Moderation*](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/) that kind of serves as a basis for all SE sites. For more info, browse around on the [Stack Exchange Meta site](http://meta.stackexchange.com), and especially check out the [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites), which includes a lot of information that has been condensed into the [Help Center](http://biology.stackexchange.com), but also many more tidbits, suggestions, no-no's, and discussions. Do all that, and you'll have a much better idea of How Things Work™. If only all new visitors read all that...

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying to read and learn as much as possible (mostly by observing others). I'll do my best to catch up. Thanks again for the sources.